# HTC HERO Android 2.2

Tags: 2.2-froyo, htc-hero

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my phone get the Android 2.2 update (FroYo)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/when-will-my-phone-get-the-android-2-2-update-froyo)

Will my HTC HERO get Android 2.2?

I guess i can upgrade to Anrdoid 2.2 but can i get Sense UI on Android 2.2 for hero?

Comment: Who is your carrier?

Comment: I live in Norway, the question is just will it ever by supported by my phone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no. But if you root your Hero, the answer is definitively yes. [Check out XDA Forums and lookup your device](http://forum.xda-developers.com/index.php). I know for the CDMA hero there are already 2.2 ROMs ripe for the picking.

Answer (score 2):

Since it has been officially discontinued, I doubt it. Although Sprint is rolling out an update in October, it doesn't appear to be Froyo. In fact they've said as much: http://androidspin.com/2010/09/26/sprint-hero-getting-some-love/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a GSM Hero (Europe) you should look up Villain Rom. It's the most mature rom with auto updating and such. There are both Sense UI ROMs and Stock Android 2.2 ROMs. 
http://www.villainrom.co.uk/forum/

Answer (score 0):

My Sprint Hero is running Froyo, a Cyanogen build.  Runs great.